# Should I do a Master's degree if I am already employed in the field?

Tags: masters, education

I am very torn about whether to take the plunge to do a Master's degree. I graduated a few years ago with  BSc in Maths which I didn't particularly enjoy, only the statistics and programming courses. I then got a job at a big technology company in their R&D department doing research and applications of data science. I thoroughly enjoy the work I do but I am also interested in developing my skills further. I want to gain a deeper understanding of artificial intelligence and am also interested in spatial data science. I am not sure whether I should continue in this role or at a different company and learn on the job or invest some time and money into full-time education. I am also not sure whether in the future with only an undergraduate degree I would be able to progress in my field. 
I am also concerned about age, whether it's wise to go back to university at 25.

Comment: This isn't really a question about Academia. https://workplace.stackexchange.com/ is a better place for such questions.

Answer (score 1):

First, research if your company has incentive programs for higher education. Many top companies offer partial/full tuition reimbursement to qualifying employees to pursue a masters. If this is the case, use the program to take 1 or two classes a semester. Frankly, a person with a bachelors can usually attain the same titles and salaries as a masters. The biggest difference in salaries/titles/responsibilities are between masters and PhDs. The main difference is that a PhD can be a PI on research grants/studies.
I went back to University when I was 30. Sometimes the market calls for a change in careers. But as I stated before, you may not have to "return". If your company is flexible, you could attain a masters on the side within 3-4 years by doing classes in the evening/weekend/online.

Answer (score 1):

First off, your age has next to nothing to do with when you are able/should go back to college. When I was in college, I saw people in their 70-80's taking courses. My mother got her masters, after taking classes on and off for decades, in her 50's or 60's (I don't remember which anymore). I have one sister that got her Masters in her late 40's, and another sister with multiple Bachelors and Masters degrees over the course of a couple decades.

I'm 41 and I want to go back to get a Bachelors in robotics, but part of that is only because I only have an Associates degree. I know a BA/BS will look better on a resume, so it's partly just vanity at this point, because I already have 20+ years experience between computer hardware and software. I went to university at 19, failed to get that degree for many reasons, including money, then went back to college to get my Associates at 26.

The real question is: what do you intend to accomplish by going back to school?

Do you really need a Masters to do what you want? Sometimes yes and sometimes no. A Masters can get you slightly further in the door at hiring time and sometimes it can completely disqualify you. It can further you by showing you likely have more knowledge and stamina at a position than others without, but after the initial resume review, it likely won't really matter that much. It can disqualify you for some jobs that "don't want to pay that much". Even if you ask for less than they expect, they'll likely wonder why you are willing to work "for that little". I've seen senior level jobs in the computer sector that didn't require any degree and I've also seen entry level positions that required a Masters. Every job and every company is different, for better or worse.

If you are simply interested in the topics and don't specifically need the degree, just take the courses you want and don't bother about a degree course. After a couple of years you might find you have met the requirements for a degree by accident and can get it then, but it doesn't have to be the goal.

Also, there's lots of online and book learning you can do without a school being involved. YouTube, pod casts, blogs, Instructables.com, and more sites have the kind of things you're interested in for free. There's likely all kinds of informal and semi-formal groups on the topics you want in your area. Search FaceBook Groups, LinkedIn, MeetUp.com, and other social sites to see what's available. If there isn't anything, maybe you can start a group. With you being in a computer field, you might even be able to meet with people nationally and internationally through video conferencing. You might also try looking into local maker/hacker-spaces to find people with similar interests.

With this site being an academic forum, the "of course" answer is to get the degree, but there's much more out there to think about than simply more schooling.